# how do i log in to my website using facebook social login

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am stuck with loggin into my website using facebook but i keep getting this this problem that when ever i click on the facebook log in button the pop up shows and hides immediately

i already tried using the facebook document code for web login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Facebook Login JavaScript Example</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into your app or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this app.';
    }
  }

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '{your-app-id}',
    cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
    xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
    version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.8
  });

  // Now that we've initialized the JavaScript SDK, we call 
  // FB.getLoginStatus().  This function gets the state of the
  // person visiting this page and can return one of three states to
  // the callback you provide.  They can be:
  //
  // 1. Logged into your app ('connected')
  // 2. Logged into Facebook, but not your app ('not_authorized')
  // 3. Not logged into Facebook and can't tell if they are logged into
  //    your app or not.
  //
  // These three cases are handled in the callback function.

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>

<!--
  Below we include the Login Button social plugin. This button uses
  the JavaScript SDK to present a graphical Login button that triggers
  the FB.login() function when clicked.
-->

<fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
</fb:login-button>

<div id="status">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> i used this link below

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

thanks for your help

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the section about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Social Plugin: The Login Button Facebook offers a host of what they call social plugins. The one we are interested in is the Login Button. Here are the basic steps involved in getting the button onto your webpage:

You need a Facebook app for your site. Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ and click on the "New App" button.

Your "App Display Name" can be something meaningful. I usually go with the domain name for the site. You can use this same app for other purposes in the future as well. The "App Namespace" needs to be something that does not contain any special characters. I usually use my app display name without spaces, periods, etc. Now you need to enter your "App Domain" and Website "Site URL." For the app domain enter the domain name on which your site is hosted. For the site URL enter the full URL of your website. For example, if your domain is name.com then your site URL should be something like http://www.your_domain.com. Save your changes once you have the proper information entered. Now you will have a page that shows yours "App ID" and "App Secret". Just leave that page open because you will need your app ID when you add the login button code to your page. Now we need to go get the login button code from Facebook. Go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/ and click the "Get Code" button. Copy the HTML5 code from the first box and for now put it just below the body tab of your webpage. The code should look something like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
   (function(d, s, id) {
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {
       return;
     }
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

In the code be sure to replace APP_ID with the app id you created for your Facebook app. Now paste the code from the second box in whatever place you want the login button to reside. The code should look something like:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

data-show-faces equals  false because with it set to true the logout button will show when the user is logged in.